# How to add a line over numbering in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

I want to add a line in footer over the page numbering in lyx, how can I do that ? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a standard `book` or `article` class:

<kbd>Document</kbd>
→ <kbd>Setings ...</kbd> 
→→     <kbd>Page layout ...</kbd> 
→→→     <kbd>Page layout dialog</kbd> 
→→→→     <kbd>Page style:</kbd>  select <kbd>fancy</kbd>
→→→→→     <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Apply</kbd>

Then ...

<kbd>Document</kbd>
→ <kbd>Setings ...</kbd> 
→→ <kbd>LaTeX Preamnle</kbd>
→→→ Type `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}` in the right empty window
→→→→     <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Apply</kbd>

Writing in LaTeX directly, this is equivalent to type in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

For more information about headers and footers, see the manual of this package (run `texdoc fancyhdr`).

Comment: Love you man, you are a life saver.